# Slick slider messing with font in complete different location on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, bootstrap-4, slick.js

## Slick slider messing with font in complete different location on Chrome

Very weird situation.
When my slick slider goes to the next / previous image one 3-column block with red titles in them the font goes a little darker and then comes back normaly as the slider finished sliding one element.

It looks like the font ins "blinking"

## What I tried:

- downgrading slick back to 1.6.0
- remove all classes of the 3-column block and style each element
- different window-sizes
- different browsers (Firefox & Internet Explorer)
- Validate Source-Code (NU checker showed no errors.)

#### Nothing is working.

It works fine in Firefox & IE but not in Chrome - can't test in safari but somebody told me the same is happening there.

### My Chrome - version: 87.0.4280.66

I really don't know what else i could do.

## Here is a GIF of what's happening:

[image: Showing font-blinking]

## Simplified Sourcecode (In Execution | Slick already initiated)

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="robots" content="all,follow">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.componentator.com/spa.min@14.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,200,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/widgets.css?ts=gnt3q">
    <script src="//cdn.componentator.com/spa.min@14.js"></script>
    <meta name="keywords" content="Node.js, eshop, ecommerce, Total.js">
    <meta name="author" content="Peter Širka">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/default/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="/default/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/default/css/slick.css">
    <script src="/default/js/slick.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/default/css/default.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/default/css/style.css">
    <script src="/default/js/default.js"></script>
    <script src="/default/js/custom.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>

<body data-jc="exec,binder,modificator">
    <div data-jc="loading" class="ui-loading hidden">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div data-jc="shoppingcart" data-jc-path="shoppingcart" data-jc-config="discount:0"></div>
    <div data-jc="message" data-jc-config="button:Schließen" class="ui-message hidden"></div>
    <div data-jc="autocomplete" class="ui-autocomplete-container hidden">
        <div class="ui-autocomplete" style="max-height: 200px;">
            <ul></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-spacer"></div>
    <main class="main" style="min-height: 939px;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <section class="body">
                        <div>
                            <div></div>
                            <div class="productslider">
                                <div class="row slick-initialized slick-slider"><button class="slick-prev slick-arrow" aria-label="Previous" type="button" style="">Previous</button>
                                    <div class="slick-list draggable">
                                        <div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; width: 2400px; transform: translate3d(-1280px, 0px, 0px);">
                                            <div class="col-md-3 slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="-6" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 80px;" tabindex="-1">
                                                <a href="#test1" tabindex="-1">
                                                    <div class="product">
                                                        <p class="product-title">Test 1</p><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" border="0" alt="Test 1">
                                                    </div>
                                                </a></div>
                                            <div class="col-md-3 slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="-5" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 80px;" tabindex="-1">
                                                <a href="#test1" tabindex="-1">
                                                    <div class="product">
                                                        <p class="product-title">Test 1</p><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" border="0" alt="Test 1">
                                                    </div>
                                                </a></div>
                                            <div class="col-md-3 slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="-4" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 80px;" tabindex="-1">
                                                <a href="#test1" tabindex="-1">
                                                    <div class="product">
                                                        <p class="product-title">Test 1</p><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" border="0" alt="Test 1">
                                                    </div>
                                                </a></div>
                                            <div class="col-md-3 slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="-3" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 80px;" tabindex="-1">
                                                <a href="#test1" tabindex="-1">
                                                    <div class="product">
                                                        <p class="product-title">Test 1</p><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" border="0" alt="Test 1">
                                                    </div>
                                                </a></div>
                                            <div class="col-md-3 slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="-2" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 80px;" tabindex="-1">
                                                <a href="#test1" tabindex="-1">
                                                    <div class="product">
                                                        <p class="product-title">Test 1</p><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" border="0" alt="Test 1">
                                                    </div>
                                                </a></div>
                                            <div class="col-md-3 slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="-1" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 80px;" tabindex="-1">
                                                <a href="#test1" tabindex="-1">
                                                    <div class="product">
                                                        <p class="product-title">Test 1</p><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" border="0" alt="Test 1">
                                                    </div>
                                                </a></div>
                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </div><button class="slick-next slick-arrow" aria-label="Next" type="button" style="">Next</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div></div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer class="">
        <div class="container">
            <hr><br>
            <div class="row" style="
                font-size: 40px !important;
            ">
                <div class="col-md-4 text-md-left text-center">
                    <h2>TEXT 1</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-md-center text-center">
                    <h2>TEXT 2</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-md-right text-center">
                    <h2>TEXT 3</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <div class="scrollToTop" style="display: none;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Maybe you know why this is happening / you have the same problem

Would really appreciate it,
as i already spent hours debugging this...

Comment: Just a wild guess: Try giving the footer `position: relative; z-index: 1;`

Comment: @BjørnNyborg ... yeah it worked lol. What i did: z-index over 9000, position relative and instead of the font-weight normal i used bold.

Now there is no flickering anymore...

I guess there are 2 issues, custom font is not made to display font-weight: normal; but it can display font-weight: bold; pretty good.

Now color is fitting and the flickering is not happening anymore.

Thank you mate.

Comment: No problem. :) I posted an answer that you can accept. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the footer `position: relative;` and `z-index: 1;`
In this way you take the element out of the stacking context, and that usually solves the problem.

Comment: thanks mate.

That's the worst part of being the only web dev on your team - you can't just ask somebody else to look over the code haha.

well deserved.

Comment: No problem! If you need some help, feel free to reach out. I do some freelancing in my spare time. 